# What type of background is this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, background, patterns

I'm working on a special project for my college, and saw this pretty cool background in our newsletter. I would like to use it for my project, but I can't seem to create it right.

Any help would be nice.

I've tried just making a square and using Pattern/Make and adjustments. But mine comes out too large.

[image: Pattern Background]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Illustrator....

Create a square and circle, centered...

[image]

Remove the stroke and fill from the square and *move the square behind all other objects*....

[image]

Select all that and drag it to the **Swatches Panel** to create a pattern swatch.

Draw a new rectangle and apply the new pattern you created as a fill...

[image]

If it's not the size you want... choose `Object > Transform > Scale...` from the menu.

**Tick the Transform pattern** box. This *should* UNtick the `Transform Objects` box. If it doesn't untick the transform objects. Then just enter a percentage of reduction to resize the pattern....

[image]

@Cai pointed out that the dots are staggered... easily done...

Double-click the new pattern in the **Swatches Panel**. When the `Pattern Options` Panel pops open, select `Brick By Row` from the `Tile Type` drop down, then just exit pattern editor choosing to save the edits.

[image]

<sub>Illustrator screenshots from AICS6 because I'm not a big fan of CC.... but it's the same basic thing.</sub>

---

<s>--- Ooops original answer failed to realize this was an AI question.... below is Photoshop... -----</s>

It's just a dot....

[image]

You can create the pattern then apply it as a pattern overlay then adjust scale to your liking...

[image]

Comment: OPs pattern dots are offset so you'd need two dots in your square, but yeah 'tis just a dot

Comment: Oops missed that.. but updated answer to address it.

Comment: Ah yes, pattern offset makes much more sense.

Comment: The OP tagged with InDesign as well so perhaps not strikethru your PhotoShop answer after all -- 

Comment: Also possibly useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9VsygMMz80

Comment: Thanks so much! I manged to recreate exactly how it looks!